# Results of If condition not as expected

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

`If` Condition is not working in excel:

[image: If Condition is not working in excel]

I am working on excel but I am not finding error. anybody can solve my issue?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, you should know that Excel evaluates `"">5` as `TRUE` because `""` is blank text, not empty or zero.

Comment: Try to change the Formula to: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Djj6a.png

Answer (score 2):

Your `IF` function is working exactly as you have written it.  If you select a cell and then use the Formula Evaluation tool, you may understand better.

For example (your first unwanted result):

```
D7: =IF(D6>5,$D$2-5,"")
```

Since `D6` = `6`, and since `6` > `5`, the formula will return `condition_if_true` or `5`.

You can see similar in evaluating the other incorrect results.

To get the sequence you want, if you have Excel O365, you can use:

```
=SEQUENCE(5,,10,-1)
```

In earlier versions, and using `IF`, you can try:

```
=IF(AND(D2>6,D2<>""),$D$2-ROWS($1:1),"")
```

and fill down. (*The `ROWS` function will increase by one for each row you fill down*)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the Formula to :
[image]

Comment: But that doesn’t produce the result that the OP wants!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your are using a numeric comparison on (empty) strings and numbers. Just change the formulas (using D9 as example) like this:

```
=IF(D8>5,$D$2-7,"")
```

into

```
=IF(VALUE("0"&D8)>5,$D$2-7,"")
```

The new formula will just add a leading zero to any numaric value, or replace an empty string with a zero, and then convert the result into a number, which makes the numeric comparison work again.